# How to connect a Laravel app to MySQL using MAMP?

Tags: mysql, laravel, mamp

### SOLVED: I followed what this website said http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=980 I just added 'unix_socket' to the mysql array and it worked!

I am following the Laravel quick start guide at http://laravel.com/docs/quick

I have everything set up and am using MAMP. When I try and view the `/public/users` page, I am hit with:

> PDOException
>
> SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" error.

My `database.php` file looks like so:

```php
'mysql' => array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'todolist',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => 'root',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
),
```

My MAMP displays:

```
host        localhost
port        8889
user        root
password    root
```

My question is, is the MySQL on MAMP's separate from the MySQL tables I have created locally? I am assuming yes because I am not able to see the tables on PHPMyAdmin. If so, is there a way to connect my Laravel app to MAMP's MySQL?

Comment: Hey there. Good question, but I'm afraid your link is broken.. care to fix it? I would really read that forum page...

Answer (score 13):

MAMPs MySQL is running on port 8889, so add `'port' => '8889'` to your config array

Comment: I added 'port' => '8889' to the array but now I am getting a "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'todolist.users' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `users`) (Bindings: array ( ))" error. So, I tried running the migration again but I get the message "Nothing to migrate"

Comment: This is a separate issue. Laravel wont create your users table for you, you need to create it yourself by either writing a migration or manually via a MySQL interface

Comment: You can also change the host line to read: 
        'host' => 'localhost:8889'
This is equivalent to Erin's comment but condensed down to one line.