# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61) error Laravel 4.1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I am receiving the following error on my localhost for Laravel 4.1 (using MAMP)

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)
```

It points to:

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/crowdsets/laravel-master/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php
```

This is the function it is pointing to:

```
public function createConnection($dsn, array $config, array $options)
    {
        $username = array_get($config, 'username');

        $password = array_get($config, 'password');

        return new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
    }
```

Up to this point, I had not received this error.

I have a local environment and production environment set up (the default).

in config/local/database.php I have:

```
'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => '127.0.0.1',
            'database'  => 'database',
            'username'  => 'root',
            'password'  => 'root',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),
```

Comment: Guess mysql is not running.

Comment: I had this error when in local enviroment was. In local environment  database was connecting to default port and so array index port was skipped. In production there was set different port. And local enviroment tried to use production port because what is not defined in local environment - is taken from default environment and show this stupid error, not mentioning anythjing about port :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An error like that means the server itself is not even reachable. Did you start MySQL in MAMP?

Also, how have you started MAMP? With the standard MySQL `3306` port? Or the alternative port MAMP uses for non-admins: `8889`?

I bet your server is running, but is attempting to connect to `3306` so you need to set the port to `8889`. Change your config to be like this; note the addition of the `port` param:

```
'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => '127.0.0.1',
            'port'      => '8889',
            'database'  => 'database',
            'username'  => 'root',
            'password'  => 'root',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),
```

**EDIT:** I just found [this question thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241721/how-to-connect-a-laravel-app-to-mysql-using-mamp) that addresses the issue of connecting Laravel to MAMP via port `8889`.

Comment: This was the issue but weirdly enough, it seems that my app isn't reading my local environment that I have set up.  Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Sorry, I meant environment configuration.  One for local and one for production.