# Connecting to remote mysql works in terminal, not via PHP PDO script

Tags: mysql, pdo

I am facing a weird problem here
we have a server A where the app files are stored
and B server with database

Tried to connect via command prompt from server A to B using the command

```
mysql -h xx.xx.xx.xx -u root -p password - and it worked
```

NOw i tried to create a php script in server A to connect to server B
the command is

```
$this->db=new PDO('mysql:host=xx.xx.xx.xx;dbname=databasename','root','password');
```

> Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL
>   server on 'xx.xx.xx.xx' (13) Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to
>   MySQL server on 'xx.xx.xx.xx' (13)'

Unable to find a solution on this.

Can any help on this?

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it working by running a command in the database server :)

```
setsebool httpd_can_network_connect_db=1
```

thanks for the replies yycdev

Comment: if @yycdev helped you find the answer you should edit accept his answer

Comment: Google helped me to find the answer :)

Comment: Apparently you need to add a -P for it to survive reboot (see http://serverfault.com/a/456875)

Comment: Also you mean the web server, not the database server

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying the port in your connection string and ensure the database server is set to allow remote connections and the port is open on your firewall (both of these I suspect are already done as you are able to connect via the terminal but it never hurts to verify and check things).

Change your PDO connection and add the port=3306 or if you're using MAMP use port 8889

```
$this->db=new PDO('mysql:host=xx.xx.xx.xx;port=3306;dbname=databasename','root','password');
```

Another thing to check is if – SELinux is blocking network connections. Login as root and run

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1
```

Comment: Yes i already tried using the port number. And the server supports remote connections too. its pretty strange..

Comment: Consider looking at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23532323/sqlstatehy000-2003-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-127-0-0-1-61-error-l

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about that, but try to place the **port** in back of the script:

```
$this->db=new PDO('mysql:host=xx.xx.xx.xx;dbname=databasename','root','password',3306);
```