# php pdo in linux, not able to connect to remote mysql server but in wamp it's working fine

Tags: php, mysql, linux

**i think this question is answered some where but i could not find it, so may be some one could save my time:**

```
webserver = > PHP5.5,mariadb linux-Centos7  --mariadb is stop --10.0.0.1

dbserver  = > PHP5.5,mariadb linux-Centos7  --httpd is stop   --10.0.0.2
```

in **dbserver** i have create a mysql-user and granted to database,allow port 3306 in firewall which

**from webserver i am able to access database server:**

> mysql -u dbuser -h 10.0.0.2 -P 3306 -p dbase    -- success

my.conf  --    #bind-address = x.x.x.x

## wamp- 10.0.0.3:

installed in windows, hosted the APP, granted database to wampuser@10.0.0.3 in the dbserver-10.0.0.2 and it's working fine.

## but

in linux-webwerver 10.0.0.1

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

class Database {

    protected $dbHosts = '10.0.0.2';
    protected $dbUsers = 'dbuser';
    protected $dbPasss = 'pssWrd';
    protected $dbNames = 'dbase';
    protected $dbPort = "3306";
    protected $conn;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->dbHosts;port=$this->dbPort;dbname=$this->dbNames", $this->dbUsers, $this->dbPasss);
        $this->conn->exec("SET NAMES UTF8");
    }

}
?>
```

here is the error i get:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.0.0.2'
```

what am i missing?

regards

Comment: just verify your network settings like firewall.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, firewall is allowing because when i try to access the remote-mysql from terminal it's accessing i can query,select...etc from webserver--- #mysql -u dbuser -h 10.0.0.2 -P 3306 -p dbase     working

Comment: Well it sounds extremely strange because PDO does not connect on its own, it does exactly the same as mysql command line client. When strange things happen, one should look for typos. Or check network settings again.

Comment: Try to check answer here if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27023318/connecting-to-remote-mysql-works-in-terminal-not-via-php-pdo-script

Comment: Did-not worked..Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.0.0.2

Comment: do you run your script from the command line or by calling a web-server?

Comment: i run the script on db-server on command line like, #command....

Comment: wait. you need to run your script on the **web** server. So again: You have a PHP script located on the web-server 10.0.0.1. Can you run it from the command line like `php test.php`?

Comment: thank you, i run (setsebool httpd_can_network_connect_db=1) on webserver command line(terminal) and now it's working fine

Comment: @YourCommonSense, may i ask u a question.

Comment: Just ask your question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105527/discussion-between-user3286490-and-your-common-sense).