# Laravel fails to connect to other database servers

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo

I have been using Laravel for a while but mostly on a single database server.

Now, my client has got atleast 5 database from multiple database servers in the same network.

I am able to confirm the communication in between servers using `ping` through ssh and also using the 
`mysqli_connect` to check the database connections.

However, when I use laravel through its database.php (mysql configs) like :

```
// This setup is working fine (using localhost)
'mysql' => array(
                'driver'    => 'mysql',
                'host'      => 'localhost',
                'database'  => 'dbname',
                'username'  => 'user',
                'password'  => 'password',
                'charset'   => 'utf8',
                'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
                'prefix'    => '',
            ),


// Other DB (which is failing to connect) but i can confrim the connection using a file outside 
// the laravel app through mysqli

        'other_db_connection' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => '192.168.33.241',
            'database'  => 'dbname',
            'username'  => 'username',
            'password'  => 'password',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),

        'another_db_connection' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => '192.168.33.211',
            'database'  => 'dbname',
            'username'  => 'username',
            'password'  => 'password',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),
```

and using the `new PDO`

```
// This connectiion functions with no problem
$conn1 = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname;port=3306','username','password');

if($conn1) {
                echo 'connected';
            }

// But this returns an error
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=192.168.33.241;dbname=dname;port=3306','username','password');

        if($conn) {
            echo 'connected';
        }

// Also, i have no problems using the DB:: or even the model as long as the host is the localhost
```

it fails to connect, both the PDO and the laravel default DB feature only works if the host is the localhost.

For some reason it throws back an error like this if i use the other servers ip, which is where i would like to communicate with:

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.33.241' (13)`
`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.33.211' (13)`

When i try using the server ip or the main domain name to connect.

Am I missing something? Why is it that I can connect only on the local db server which is `localhost`
and not to any other database servers? But I can connect to them with no problem if I use say an index.php file from outside the laravel application and use the mysqli_connect to make queries and make connections?

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Can you post the full `database.php` (with passwords removed)?  Also, how are you using them in your code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23532323/sqlstatehy000-2003-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-127-0-0-1-61-error-l

Comment: @msturdy .. Hi I have edited as per your request, hope its clearer.

Comment: @MarcoMura .. i dont see how this post helps. I have seen this already and it addresses the issue in regards with the MAMP ports.. all ports from the servers that we use is 3306.. I mentioned that I have no problem connecting on the localhost db server.. the problem underlies once I try to make a connection to a different db server.. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can access all the connections you have specified within database.php with:

```
$user = DB::connection('other_db_connection')
```

You don't need to setup new PDO connections or similar, will work like above for you

Comment: Hi, yeah I also tried that already. It still shows the same error.. It seems that I can connect to any of the db servers if I access it oustide laravel.. but when i use it inside the laravel app it throws the error.

Comment: and all of your connections are within the connections array?

Comment: Yes sir.. its so weird that I can only access if db under the localhost, but not under other hosts.

Comment: Im also looking at it from the network point of view, but the servers seems to be able to communicate if using the php mysqli ..

Comment: Really weird. You said you are able to access the other connections from another file outside of laravel. Is this other file located on the same server as laravel is?

Comment: Yes.. both directories are in the /var/www/html ... i created an index file on a folder called test.. from there, all connections are possible..

Comment: Is it at all possible that this has something to do with the <Virtualhost> setup? as I have made the laravel/public to be the main directory if users go to the browser using the domain name. so if they type domain.name.com in reality, it uses the laravel/public path so basically, domain.name.com/home is infact the laravel route of home

Comment: It shouldn't have an effect at all... @GitKidd