# PDOException SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out on my local computer

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Recently I've imported my code from my server but the local code can't connect to the remote mysql database.

So I have 2 questions :
- Can I access to my remote databse
If yes : why is my code not working ?
If no : is there a way to bypass this problem ? (I don't want to make a copy of my mysql database that would run on my local computer)

My code :
`$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host={$db_host};dbname={$db_name}", $db_user, $db_pass);`

My remote server is from LWS.

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23532323/sqlstatehy000-2003-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-127-0-0-1-61-error-l

Comment: It doesn't because I'm trying to acces a remote mysql server, not a local server

Comment: what is LWS? Explain the hosting environment and what settings you can make. Normally it is a non-starter to help without adequately documenting settings, which is why, for instance, the answer below says "go read this", which is a comment.

Comment: LWS is the society that host my server. I have only access to PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: LWS doesnt allow remote DB access. If you are on a dedicated server you may configure you MySQL to have remove access. On a shared server no way to have remote access. it for security reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For remote access, You should to enable remote access to your MySQL Server.
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html