# MAMP on Windows - ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) when trying to log-in into MySQL via command line

Tags: mysql, mamp

I am reading the book 'PHP and MySQL Web Development(Developer's Library)' Fourth Edition by Luke Welling and Laura Thomson and i'm in the part where i need to log in and create a database via the command line(cmd) of Windows but when i am trying to log in, i am getting the following error:

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

I am using MAMP on Windows 10. What i've done in so far is i ran the MAMP server(MySQL Server is shaded green: turned on) and change the directory on the command line where the MySQL is located. Is there a detail that i forgot to do?

Comment: Looks like MySQL server is actually not running.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLSTATE\[HY000\] \[2003\] Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61) error Laravel 4.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23532323/sqlstatehy000-2003-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-127-0-0-1-61-error-l)

Comment: The MySQL Server on my MAMP Application window is shaded green(turned on). I've have researched that the MySQL must be running in the services of windows. What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

See this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23532364/7618391

For me, I was using a port different than the standard MySQL port.  Once I changed the MySQL port in MAMP to 3306, it worked fine.
Good luck.